# How to transfer date data to another form's datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a gridview and when I click edit, I open another form and transfer gridview cell data.

When I debug it can get my date but datetimepicker value is not changing on my form.

I have two form. Form1 has my datetimepicker, and form2 has datagridview. When I right click "edit" on datagridview, it opens my form1 and transfer all data from gridview to form1. Everything is working expect datetimepicker values are not changing.

My code:

```
DateTime date= DateTime.Parse(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
form1.DateTimePicker.Value = date;
```

I stuck and need help.

Comment: Where do you define `form1`?..

Comment: I have two form. Form1 has my datetimepicker, and form2 has datagridview. When I right click "edit" on datagridview, it opens my form1 and transfer all data from gridview to form1. Everything is working expect datetimepicker values are not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after you assign the date:

```
form1.Show()
form1.Invalidate();
form1.Refresh();
```

Comment: No, it is not giving any error or exception. Just value isn't changing on my form

Comment: @Dave then show us more code please, what is the method that code is part of etc

Comment: That is my all code. After that code I have only this:
 form1.Show();
 this.Hide();

Comment: @Dave then i'm afraid you're looking for the problem in wrong place, please debug the code you gave us and give us either more code or info. Is the form1.DateTimePicker.Value changes right after you do the assign?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function on form1. something similar to the following:

```
public void UpdateForm1(DateTime? newDate)
{
   dgv.Rows[0][1].value = newDate == null? "": newDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

From form2 you can call this function on datetime changed

```
Form1.UpdateForm1(this.datetimePicker.value);
```

Hope it helps